# Decrypting a message using smart contract

Tags: encryption, zksnark, zero-knowledge, zksync

Is this possible to send a message from address A to address B on Ethereum (or another type of blockchain), and it is so that address B can't open the message, unless a smart contract permits it sometime in the future (without human intervention) based on a specific condition/logic (for example time, market conditions, etc) via ZK or encryption in a way that the message is private except for address B, etc. Would really appreciate it if you can help me with this. Thanks